# Change class of every second instance of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, list, class

I am working on a Wordpress site and I want to create an unordered list that has categories. The categories consist of subjects such as : Math, English, Science, etc. A user can upload a file related to one of these categories and give a brief description of the file. However I don't want the categories to repeat themselves for every instance ex:

-English
    Hamlet by Shakespeare
    Read 1 chapter every week and take notes

-English
    Reading Assignment
Read all 12 questions and answer in full sentences.

Instead I would like the first instance of this category to appear and have other posts that are of the same category to be appended to the first instance.
example:

-English

-Hamlet by Shakespeare
    Read 1 chapter every week and take notes

-Reading Assignment
Read all 12 questions and answer in full sentences.

This is what I have so far:

```
cat = document.getElementsByClassName("catname"); 

for(var i =0; i < cat.length ; i++){
  if (cat[i].innerHTML == "General"){
    cat[i].className = "hide";
   }
  else if(cat[i].innerHTML == "English"){
    cat[i].className = "hide"; 
   }
  else if(cat[i].innerHTML == "French"){
    cat[i].className = "hide"; 
   }
  else if(cat[i].innerHTML == "Math"){
    cat[i].className = "hide"; 
   }
  else if(cat[i].innerHTML == "Science"){
   cat[i].className = "hide";
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than manipulating the category labels after the page has been generated, why not store the categories explicitly in the backend?  Make each subject a Wordpress category, then display lists of the posts by category.  You could do that using a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/list-category-posts/) or with your own PHP code in the template (based on [this post](http://wesbos.com/wordpress-list-posts-by-category/)):

```
<?php $cats = get_categories(); 
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    $cat_id= $cat->term_id;
    echo "<h2>".$cat->name."</h2>";
    query_posts("cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=100");
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I am currently already using a Wordpress plugin called wp-types in order to display the categories I have to use this code:                   <wpv-loop> 
  <div class="catname">[types field="categories" id=""][/types]</div> 
  <ul> <li><a href="[types field="file"][/types]">[types field="file-title" link="true"][/types]</a> <br/> Description: [types field="description" id=""][/types]</li> </ul> </wpv-loop>

Comment: So how would I do what you have specified using this plugin specifically ?